# How to use aspnet_compiler

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, aspnet-compiler

Afterlooking at this [post][1], I thought that I would give it a go.

So, in my Post Build Event, I've put...

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler -v / -p "$(ProjectDir)\"

...then clicked Build Solution.

Unfortunately, I got the following error:  "Could not load type 'MyWebProject.UI.Global'.   C:\global.asax  1   MyWebProject.UI"

Any ideas why?  To my knowledge, I don't even have a C:\global.asax file.

Ultimately, I want to be able to check my ASPX pages for errors.  At the moment, the only way in which I can do this is by navigating to the page.

Any other suggestions/approaches welcome!

Thanks,

ETFairfax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/05/compiling-aspx-templates-using.html

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p "website complete path" d:\testPrecompileFolder -f

Answer (score 1):

Your post build event is pointless.  If you can precompile, then you don't have any errors that aspnet_compiler would catch anyway.  Runtime errors are another matter of course.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to precompile the site using Visual Studio? Via the Build -> Publish Web Site menu?

Comment: I've not used that before, but yes I can.